# How does a tagging article database look like?

Tags: mysql, php

I have a article website and each article has some tags. How should be my database structure?

This is my article table (*article*):

```
article_id (key)  |  article_content  |  article_title  |  article_lang_id
```

This is the list of my tags *(tag_list):*

```
tag_list_id (key)  |  tag_list_name  |  tag_list_description
```

And this is my tag table *(tag_link)*:

```
  tag_id (key)   |   article_id (f-key)  |   tag_list_id (f-key)
```

I echo the article content with php, how can I echo (I mean showing tag bellow content) tags bellow the content?

This is my question:

**1- How can I show each content tags near content?**

(each content can has less than 5 tags)

**2-What is the MYSQL query that I can run to select my tags with content?**
(is there any professional MySQL orders to select content with tags form tag_link and then select the name of tag from tag_list and then show it near article, can I do it with MySQL orders like join, having, on and several other? How?)

**3-Is my database structure for tagging true?**

(I can do this with php variables and ... , but I need to do it by MySQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 & 2:use inner join

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

3:
yes your structure is true